# How to start Firefox with with specific profile Selenium Python geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Here is my code:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\kvycjolb.Prdel')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Im not getting any error and firefox starts, but it just does not load with this profile: I have tried changing / to // etc.. but no luck.

This also does not work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\kvycjolb.Prdel")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\aprog\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Im getting error:

```
C:\aprog>testff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\aprog\testff.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, e
xecutable_path="C:\\aprog\\geckodriver.exe")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matchin
g set of capabilities
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the official answer is found in [documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/CrashReports.html).

Presently that is:

```
# Custom profile folder to keep the minidump files
profile = tempfile.mkdtemp(".selenium")
print("*** Using profile: {}".format(profile))

# Use the above folder as custom profile
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("-profile")
opts.add_argument(profile)
opts.binary = "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts,
    # hard-code the Marionette port so geckodriver can connect
    service_args=["--marionette-port", "2828"])
```

Comment: I get "Undefined name 'Options'

Comment: @MatthewCox, Did you use `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options` as in documentation?

Answer (score 3):

```
def setFirefoxDriver():
    profilePath = r"PathHere" 
    driverPath  = r"pathHere\driver.exe"

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("-profile")
    options.add_argument(profilePath)

    dService = Service(driverPath)
    d = webdriver.Firefox(service=dService, options=options)

    return d

d = setFirefoxProfile()

d.get('https://www.amazon.com/)
```

- to know profile paths search in your firefox `about:support` or `about:profiles`
- You can test it loading your own profile and see if cookies are loading, ie: when I go to amazon.com amazon recognizes me.
- Notice that you can't be using the same profile in 2 different instances, so if you wanna load your profile to test in selenium you shouldn't be using that firefox profile, but another one.

Answer (score 2):

To start Mozilla Firefox with a specific Firefox Profile through `Selenium 3.4.3`, `geckodriver v0.18.0`, `Mozila Firefox 53.0` and `Python 3.6`, you need to create a separate `Firefox Profile` with the `Firefox Profile Manager` as per the documentation [**`here`**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

I have created a `Firefox Profile` by the name **`debanjan`**. This profile got stored in this subdirectory:

**"C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"**

The name of the profile (folder) is **`w8iy627a.debanjan`**. So while initiating the `WebDriver` instance we have to pass the absolute path of the `Firefox Profile` named as **`w8iy627a.debanjan`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\w8iy627a.debanjan")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I use python27, getting error: Unable to find matching set of capabilities.

Comment: Can you update your code and error in the question area for further analysis please? Thanks

Comment: Selenium, GeckoDriver, Mozilla Firefox versions please. Thanks

Comment: Firefox 54.0.1, Geckodriver 0.18.0win64

Comment: Firefox 54.0.1, Geckodriver 0.18.0win64 selenium 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Always use double backslashes in the path (for Windows paths at least):

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\kvycjolb.Prree')
```

In your code, you use both backslashes and forward slashes.

Comment: I have repaired that in code, but it did not solve the problem.